# What is the correct way to configure actors in Play 2.x?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.1

I noticed a slight difference between the documentation for 2.1 and 2.0:

**[2.0](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAkka)**

```
akka.default-dispatcher.core-pool-size-max = 64
akka.debug.receive = on
```

**[2.1](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaAkka)**

```
akka.default-dispatcher.fork-join-executor.pool-size-max =64
akka.actor.debug.receive = on
```

[Akka's own documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html) has a `core-pool-size-max` setting like 2.0, but no `pool-size-max` like 2.1. Why did this change between 2.0 and 2.1? Which is the correct way to configure Akka in Play? Is this a documentation bug in one of the versions?

(In the meantime, I'm going to try and stick both config styles in my Play 2.1 config and hope for the best).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, always use the documentation for the version you're using, in your case you're linking to the snapshot documentation which is for an unreleased Akka version (i.e. a snapshot).

Here's the 2.1.2 docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/dispatchers.html (also accessible from doc.akka.io)

When we look at that page, we see that under the *example* configuration for fork-join-executor and thread-pool-executor it says: "For more options, see the default-dispatcher section of the Configuration.", linking to:

Where we can find:

```
  # This will be used if you have set "executor = "thread-pool-executor""
  thread-pool-executor {
    # Keep alive time for threads
    keep-alive-time = 60s

    # Min number of threads to cap factor-based core number to
    core-pool-size-min = 8

    # The core pool size factor is used to determine thread pool core size
    # using the following formula: ceil(available processors * factor).
    # Resulting size is then bounded by the core-pool-size-min and
    # core-pool-size-max values.
    core-pool-size-factor = 3.0

    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based number to
    core-pool-size-max = 64

    # Minimum number of threads to cap factor-based max number to
    # (if using a bounded task queue)
    max-pool-size-min = 8

    # Max no of threads (if using a bounded task queue) is determined by
    # calculating: ceil(available processors * factor)
    max-pool-size-factor  = 3.0

    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based max number to
    # (if using a  bounded task queue)
    max-pool-size-max = 64

    # Specifies the bounded capacity of the task queue (< 1 == unbounded)
    task-queue-size = -1

    # Specifies which type of task queue will be used, can be "array" or
    # "linked" (default)
    task-queue-type = "linked"

    # Allow core threads to time out
    allow-core-timeout = on
  }
```

So to conclude, you need to set the default-dispatcher to use the `"thread-pool-executor"` if you want to use the ThreadPoolExecutor, by `akka.default-dispatcher.executor = "thread-pool-executor"` and then specify your configuration for that thread-pool-executor.

Does that help?

Cheers,
√

Comment: Amm, I don't want to change executors, just tweak the default one as in the examples in Play's config - I was just wondering as to why the docs for Play 2.1 differ from Play 2.0 - whether the was a real API change, or if this is a docs bug. Regardless, I just want to set `core-pool-size-max` or `pool-size-max`.

Comment: But you need to change the setting for the right implementation. The default-dispatcher uses fork-join-executor so you'll have to change the settings for that unless you change executor. Please refer to the documentation.